# Do chat wheel messages and map pings still appear from muted players?

Tags: steam, dota-2, voice-chat

Sadly, sometimes I have to mute and report players who are being abusive. I know that muting a player stops me from seeing chat messages and voice from them but does it also stop me from seeing their map pings and chat wheel messages?

Comment: In League of Legends muting a player does NOT prevent you from seeing their pings, I can't speak for DOTA but generally these games all follow the same patterns.

Comment: @Ender Chat wheel responses in DoTA 2 and LoL is different. Also, there are a lot of different things different from DoTA 2 and LoL, so you can't use LoL examples to answer a DoTA 2 question.

Comment: @KimMinseo that's why it's a comment and not an answer

Comment: @Ender That's reasonable, but just ensuring that the OP doesn't get the wrong idea.

Comment: I know that if someone has a communication ban, they can still use their chat wheel and ping but not talk or type, but haven't tested with simple mutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muting someone will block their chat wheel messages but won't block their pings. Which mean theorically they could spam ping and you couldn't do much about it, though, for now at least, most people still use the ping to draw attention more than being a nuisance.